# Magento Ajax check if cart already contains products or if current product is added to cart

Tags: magento

I need a simple code that would check if cart already contains products or if current product is added to cart then update a php variable without refrashing the page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the total item in shopping cart as following.

You can try something like this:

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
```

hope it will sure help you to check cart is contain product or not.

**EDIT**

if you want to use in ajax to update only top link when product is added to  cart you can get in controller like this

```
 $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';    
    $this->loadLayout();
    $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();    
    $response['toplink'] = $toplink;

// write response to ajax json

$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

and in response of ajax function you will get data in toplink and you just have to bind this response to header div

i hope this will clear your way.

Comment: This would only update it's self by refreshing the page. Is there a way to make it update automatically when the current product is added to cart without the need to refresh the entire page?

Comment: @RaduS Pls see my updated answer you will get your solution with one call to update header ajax part